# How to add hours date time picker result with Moment.JS?

Tags: momentjs

I get the value of input date in my form date time picker and get this format `15/02/2016 18.00`

How I can add thus time `10 hours` with moment js, so the result will be `16/02/2016 04.00`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use moment [`add`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/) method.

First of all, [parse](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) your input string into moment object specifying format, then add hours using `add` and finally display the result (use [`format`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) if you need a string).

Here a basic working example:

```js
// Get input value
var inputValue = $('#datetimepicker').val();
// Parse string into moment object
var momObj = moment(inputValue, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH.mm');
// Add 10 hours
momObj.add(10, 'hours');
// Show the result
$('#result').html(momObj.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH.mm'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.2/moment.min.js"></script>

<input id="datetimepicker" type="text" value="15/02/2016 18.00">

<span id="result"><span>
```

Please note that many datetimepickers have API that let you get the picker's value as Date object or as moment object, so maybe you don't have to perform the parsing step.